# Multi-user access for Mercurial sub-repositories

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

What is the right way to organize ssh access to sub-repositories in mercurial?
Consider the following situation:

```
master
|--.hgsub
|--slave1
|--slave2
```

And .hgsub:

```
slave1 = ssh://user@host://var/local/repos/slave1
slave1 = ssh://user@host://var/local/repos/slave2
```

The problem is that `.hgsub` is the part of the repository thus it is not possible (or is it?) to store various usernames in the ssh addresses of the repos. And I really want to avoid using a "global" user to access the repositories just because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have basically two choices:

1. If your subrepositories live in the same server as the container, use relative paths.  This is the most convenient solution.
2. Otherwise, you can have each user define a *subpath* rule.  Look for the *subpath* word [in this document](http://selenic.com/hg/help/config).

Comment: Thank you very much! Looks like the `subpath` rule is the best way to do this.